# android - Parallel task to execute PHP on server

Tags: php, android, static, android-asynctask

I'm developping and android application and in some point I need to get some vaue from my server. This server has a simple PHP script that just echo a value.
In order to do it, that's what I do:

```
private static String executePHP(String URL) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

    try {
    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

        return(response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return("");
    }
}
```

The method is **static**, because I call it upon an SMS arrives. Then the URL comes from the SMS text.
From the broadcastReceiver I call:

```
MainActivity.executePHP(link);
```

I want the execution of the PHP to be on a background task.

I've been reading of AsyncTask but they need and instance, which I don't have.

What's the best way to do it??
Also, have in mind that the application may not be active right now.

I'll be happy if I can only Toast the result from the PHP executing on asyncTask (or other asyncrhonus thread).

Thanks you all!!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this solve my question! Now I need to see how to handle no-internet-connection.

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391272/how-to-use-separate-thread-to-perform-http-requests)