# Why can not I use the created object? Json

Tags: java, android, json

I want to use jsonObject in my class. So I create a private jsonObject. I created it. But with getting NullPointer. Why is this happening?

My code
http://pastebin.com/NKm372LV

My Error Exeption
http://pastebin.com/cscAE1Q8

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.EraNewGames.Elbase.Schedule.onCreate(Schedule.java:32)
```

Comment: include the code on SO, not just in a link.

Comment: Put your code and error in your question. Otherwise people with same problem will not be able to find answers which may appear in your post, which defeats purpose of Stack Overflow. If your code is too long create and post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: what is the statement on Schedule.java:32? obviously there is something null value referrence

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating JSONObject in another thread - after you are trying to use it. You should read more about work with [threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads).
You can put `Log.e("asdadsadasda", jsonObject.toString());` after you were set `jsonObject` value in your other thread.

Comment: but there is a new thread in the current class. And he sees JsonObject.

This is

Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
public void run() {
                try {
                    jsonObject=new JSONObject(str);

Comment: Your `onCreate` code works parallel with another thread, so `jsonObject.toString()` calls earlier then `jsonObject=new JSONObject(str)`.

Comment: @Incover, not.

JsonCreate();
Log.e("asdadsadasda", jsonObject.toString());

JsonCreate(); This is Method

Comment: @Invocer. And if I create a onCreate  jsonObject=new JSONObject();. And  JsonCreate(){
   jsonObject.opt(str);
}

So go?

Comment: `NullPointerException` will disappear, but it will just show `{}` in your log. So, your app would not crash.

Comment: You just don't understand how separated threads works. Learn more about that, for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391272/how-to-use-separate-thread-to-perform-http-requests).