# How to load images to ImageButton from url

Tags: android, image

I need to get images from a server and load it to image-button.There are more than 50 images dynamically loading when application fragment starts. What is the best way to do this.Currently I'm using following code and when I run it application is stuck and also I followed [Android Loading Image from URL (HTTP)](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/) tutorial also, but it is not showing images when there are more than one images.

this is the code I’m currently using when but application is freezing

```
private void setListParentItemInfo(View convertView,final IPTVChannel iptvChannel){
 ImageButton logoBtn = ((ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.channelLogo));

        String image_url="http://Channel.com.au/ChannelLogos/"+Channel.getLogoName();
  logoBtn.setImageBitmap(downloadBitmap(image_url));
}


private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    // initilize the default HTTP client object
    final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    //forming a HttoGet request
    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    try {

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

        //check 200 OK for success
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode +
                    " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
            return null;

        }

        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                // getting contents from the stream
                inputStream = entity.getContent();

                // decoding stream data back into image Bitmap that android understands
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                return bitmap;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // You Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.e("ImageDownloader", "Something went wrong while" +
                " retrieving bitmap from " + url + e.toString());
    }

    return null;
}
```

How can I fix this or any other why to do this?

Comment: I recommend using [Picasso Library](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: This tutorial will help you to implement the Picasso library [Working with Android image library Picasso](https://androidcodegeeks.com/working-with-android-image-library-picasso/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Picasso Library](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

```
private void setListParentItemInfo(View convertView,final IPTVChannel iptvChannel){
 ImageButton logoBtn = ((ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.channelLogo));

 String image_url="http://Channel.com.au/ChannelLogos/"+Channel.getLogoName();
 Picasso.with(context).load(image_url).placeholder(yourDrawableImage).into(logoBtn);
}
```

Comment: do you know how to add loading image to this because this task 3s or 4s load the images?

Answer (score 3):

use picaso library , it's easy to use and fast and save cash for further uses.

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's freezing because it's running in the same thread as UI (main thread). Always use different thread (eg. [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)) for loading something from network, newer API levels shouldn't allow you to do this at all.
But definitely you should go with the [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If your using small images then you can load images by using async task like below. If you have large images then you need to follow http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

```
class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return getBitmapFromURL(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        imageButton.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String imageURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should use multiple thread per each image like it show in the [How to use separate thread to perform http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391272/how-to-use-separate-thread-to-perform-http-requests)

Answer (score 0):

Use Libraries like fresco by facebook. 
http://frescolib.org/

Using this you dont need to download the images externally.
Just set the image passing uri. It will automatically download and set it to the view.